# No functor to subcategory?

Tags: category-theory

As far as I’m aware, you can always craft a function from one set to another unless the target is the empty set. To me this is easy to understand because the empty set is...empty, so of course you can’t draw a map on it. But I’m a bit less clear on the same thing with categories. Say you have a category with objects A and B, and morphisms $f: A \to B$ and $g: B \to A$. There would be no functor from this category to a wide subcategory with only $f$ and not $g$ because you would a) lose composition and b) be mapping the hom-set of morphisms from B to A to the empty set. But to me this is just a bit weird that you don’t have a functor from a category to a  subcategory of it since it feels like there is an obvious logical relationship from the category to the subcategory in question. It feels like there should be a functor. Am I making a mistake somewhere, or is this something I just have to get used to?

Comment: Just like in the set-theoretic case, you can always map a category into a non-empty category by mapping all objects to a single object and all arrows to the identity arrow.

Comment: Thanks, Derek. If I map two objects to two objects, how does mapping one of the hom-sets to the identity arrow preserve composition? I apologize if this is trivial.

Comment: If you mean you map two objects to different objects, then there is no identity arrow to map to as there is no identity arrow between different objects. I talked about mapping all objects to the same object, so I don't understand why you asked that question. I assume that you're more wondering about how in set theory we always have an *onto* map from a set to a subset of that set. What "onto" should mean for categories is not completely trivial, but we certainly don't have that any onto mapping of objects can be extended to a functor. This isn't particularly weird; look at graph homomorphisms.

Comment: Okay, that’s basically what I figured after all. Thanks, Derek.